# Would it be a good UX if we removed the top menu altogether when inside an app?

Tags: android, ux-field

Top Menu -  Time and notification space. 
We could use that space for better purposes. Whenever the user wants the label he could just swipe down from the top.

The app is for viewing and uploading short films

Comment: Welcome to UXSE. Your question as it is now, is far too broad. You'd get better answers if you provide some images of the interface AND give us the context of the app? What is the core aim of the app?

Comment: You mean [immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive)?

Comment: @RobE Thank you! The thing is I haven't created the UI yet, was just planning the UX and got this thought.
The app is for viewing and uploading short films

Comment: @jcaron Yeah! Thanks for giving me the actual word!

Comment: You don’t need to design anything, but please provide at least a basic wireframe. Maybe it’s me, but I can’t figure what are you talking about, specially when you mention a menu that has time and what would be the “better purposes”

Comment: @Satya it’s also a link to the relevant Android documentation. Note that it makes sense only in a limited number of cases, such as playing videos, games, photo galleries, etc. Most people hate it when you remove the status bar in other types of apps. Note also that on devices that don’t have physical buttons, it also removes the navigation bar at the bottom.

Comment: @Devin I believe OP is talking about the status bar (with time, network status, notification icons, battery...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not removing that notification bar. Assuming that you are talking about the very top bar on the phone's OS that has notifications, time, battery etc (in future posts, the more specific your question the better, I had some difficulties determining what you meant).

The purpose most apps leave that alone is because that information is important to the user in almost every context, related to your app or not. Really the only exception to this is viewing content, and that bar will actively get in the way.

So if your app is viewing a short film, that would be appropriate to remove that, because that bar will take away from the video itself, and distract. But when you are talking about your main app navigation and experience, I would highly recommend following standard conventions and keeping it put.

Answer (score 0):

You can auto-hide the menu when the user is scrolling down and display the menu when the user is scrolling up. I wouldn't remove the menu altogether.